# Spawn a worker container and kill it when task completed with docker without orchestrator

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following stack of containers I run with docker compose:

- front end
- nodejs API
- mongoDB
- nodejs worker 1 to import data in DB massively on demand (through API trigger)
- nodejs worker 2 but importing data from another source
- nodejs worker clone 3...

I don't want to keep the workers up between imports, that could be weeks spaced.

What would be a good way of achieving this? Is an orchestrator necessary to avoid code shananigans?

Comment: Your fundamental choices are leaving the workers running but idle, running an orchestrator of some sort, or giving the API server unrestricted root-level access over the entire host.  My default would be to leave the workers running and use some sort of queue system like RabbitMQ to trigger them.